# How to return an auto-increment id , REST service

Tags: rest, jpa, netbeans

I'm using the netbeans helpers to create REST services. I have a "sales" table that has an auto-increment as its primary key, when the sale is saved in bbdd, the id is assigned automatically, but I need to obtain it in order to assign it to another table.
What would be the correct way to obtain the id after making the persistence?
The self-generated method that makes persistence is as follows.

```
public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}
```

And this is the method in the service

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void create(Venta entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```

In the client I use the method like this:

```
public void create_JSON(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
    webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

### }

**EDIT**
service method

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Venta insertar(Venta entity) {
    return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
```

client method

```
public <T> T insertar_JSON(Object requestEntity, Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), responseType);
}
```

that's how I'm using it in the servlet

```
venta=managerVentas.insertar_JSON(venta,Venta.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) instead, and have the create method as:

```
public T create(T entity) {
    return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
```

This will insert the entity into the database and then attach it to the persistence context. The returned entity will have the auto-incremented ID set.

Comment: thanks, I have tried but it has not worked, returns an empty sale object. I edit the post with the code that you told me to add.